# Calculating the pion decay constant in Chiral Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory, pions

I am trying to calculate the pion decay constant by following this paper [[arXiv]](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505265).

Since the decay constant is defined via

$$ \langle 0| A_\mu (0) | \phi(p)\rangle = \text{i} p_\mu F_0 \tag{3.19}$$

I would like to consider the leading order Feynman diagram, which is a pion of momentum $q$ coming in, and an axial-vector current leaving the vertex.

The relevant term in the Lagrangian is

$$ \mathcal L^{(2)} \supset \frac{F_0^2}{4}\text{Tr}(D_\mu U D^\mu U^\dagger) \tag{3.69} $$

Here we have

$$\begin{align}
D_\mu U &= \partial_\mu U - \text{i} r_\mu U + \text{i} U l_\mu \tag{3.57}\\
r_\mu &= v_\mu + a_\mu \\
l_\mu &= v_\mu - a_\mu \\ 
\partial_\mu U &= \frac{\text{i}}{F_0} \partial_\mu\phi + \mathcal O(\phi^2)
\end{align}$$

So if we restrict ourselves to terms with one pion field $\phi$ and one axial-vector current, we get

$$ \mathcal L^{(2)} \big|_{\pi a} = -F_0 a^\mu \partial_\mu \phi $$

Now we replace the derivative with $-\text{i}q_\mu$, since it's an icoming pion and take functional derivatives with respect to $a^\mu$ and $\phi$. The Feynman diagram (i.e. this one vertex) should then be given by

$$ (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(\Sigma_i p)\, \text{i} \mathcal M = \text{i} \bigg[\frac{\delta}{\delta a^\mu}\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi} \mathcal L^{(2)} \big|_{\pi a}\bigg] = -q_\mu F_0 $$

> How do I connect this result to Eq. (3.19)? I.e. what's the connection between $\text{i} \mathcal M$ and the matrix element Eq. (3.19)?

I tried to connect those terms using the LSZ reduction formula, but to no avail. Still, here's what I did:

On the one hand, the $S$-matrix element is given by

$$ \langle f |S |i\rangle \stackrel{def}= (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(\Sigma_i p)\, \text{i} \mathcal M \stackrel{diagram}= -q_\mu F_0 $$

and on the other hand, using the LSZ formula,

$$ \begin{align}
\langle f |S |i\rangle &= \bigg[ \text{i} \int \text{d}^4y \,e^{-\text{i}q\cdot x}(\square_x + m_\pi^2 ) \bigg] \langle 0| A_\mu (0) \phi(x) |0 \rangle \\
&= \text{i} \int \text{d}^4y \,e^{-\text{i}q\cdot x}(\square_x + m_\pi^2 ) \int\frac{\text{d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega_p} e^{\text{i}p\cdot x} \underbrace{\langle 0| A_\mu (0) |\phi(p) \rangle}_{\text{i}p_\mu F_0}\\
&= -F_0 \int \text{d}^4y \frac{\text{d}^3p}{(2\pi)^3 2\omega_p} \,e^{\text{i}(p-q)\cdot x} (-p^2+m_\pi^2) p_\mu \\
&= -F_0 (2\pi) \int \frac{\text{d}^3p}{2\omega_p} \,\delta^4(p-q) (-p_0^2+\textbf p^2+m_\pi^2) p_\mu\\
&= F_0 (2\pi) \int \frac{\text{d}^3p}{2\omega_p} \,\delta^4(p-q) \bigg(p_0-\sqrt{\textbf p^2+m_\pi^2}\bigg)\bigg(p_0+\sqrt{\textbf p^2+m_\pi^2}\bigg) p_\mu\\
&= F_0 (2\pi)  \,\delta(p_0-q_0) \bigg(p_0-\omega_q\bigg) q_\mu \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
since $x\delta(x)=0$.

So using the LSZ formula gives zero...

---

#### Other Approach, Direct Calculation

On the one hand,

$$ \begin{align}
\langle \Omega | A_\mu (x) \pi(y) |\Omega\rangle \sim \int\tilde{dp} e^{\text{i}p\cdot y} \langle \Omega | A_\mu (x) |\pi(p)\rangle \sim \color{red} {\text{i}} F_0 p_\mu e^{\text{i} p\cdot x}  \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}$$

but on the other hand,

$$ \begin{align}
\langle \Omega | A_\mu (x) \pi(y) |\Omega\rangle &= \langle 0 | A_\mu (x) \pi(y) e^{\text{i} \int d^4 z\mathcal L_{int}} |0\rangle\quad (\mathcal L_{int}=-F_0 A_\mu \partial^\mu\pi) \\ 
&= \underbrace{\langle 0 | A_\mu (x) \pi(y) |0\rangle}_{0}-\color{red} {\text{i}} F_0\int d^4 z \langle 0 | A_\mu (x) \pi(y) A_\nu (z) \underbrace{\partial^\nu}_{-\color{red} {\text{i}}p^\nu} \pi(z) |0\rangle + \text{higher order}
\end{align}$$

Handwaving, the contraction of both $A$s gives their propagator $G_a^{\mu\nu}(x,z)$ (does an external axial current even have a propagator since it's no dynamic field?!) and the pion contraction yields $G_\pi(y,z)$ with $\partial^\mu \to -\text{i}p^\mu$. Anyway, the point I want to highlight is, that this is a **real** expression, whereas $(\star)$ is a **complex** one.

Comment: So a field creates a pion out of the vacuum...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I've edited the question to show how far I can go. From that point on, I'm stuck.

Comment: Veeery loosely, and folding in momentum conservation and Lorentz invariance, consider something like $\phi(x)|0\rangle \propto \exp(ipx/\hbar) |\phi(p)\rangle$ and collapse all space integrations. $|\Omega\rangle = |0\rangle$, of course... The conceit is the pion decays to a state $a_\mu |0\rangle \propto p_\mu$ from Lorentz invariance and you are computing the proportionality constants. Subsequently, that state will "decay" to the two leptons the weak hamiltonian couples it to. (You are handling the strong part of the hamiltonian, only.)

Comment: Your notation is all over the place, internally, underlying your Fourier transform confusion. $|\Omega\rangle=|0\rangle$, $A_\mu = a_\mu$, and $\phi(p)$ is the Fourier transform function of $\phi(y)$. I'd call it $|\pi(p)\rangle$ to avoid confusion. The actual PCAC function you may derive, if only you shifted your variables suitably, is $\langle 0|A_\mu(x)| \pi(p)\rangle = ip_\mu F_0 e^{-ipx}$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Fair enough, I cleared up my notations and did the calculations. As you can see, this leads to zero. I only used one Fourier transformation, since there is only one Goldstone/pion field, $A_\mu$ is an external field. Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Do you really need the pion inverse propagator?

Comment: Probably not? Since there isn’t actually a propagator to cancel. However, somehow I‘m missing a factor „i“, and I don’t know where to get it from...